Derivative of structure matrices
I'm trying to follow 'Advanced Multivariate Statistics with Matrices', chapter 1.4. I know that this book is quite old, however I'm rather constrained with time and the papers I'm reading references this book. Moreover, I have asked a related but different question in math se, but I suppose since this is a statistics book I would get more answers here. I have acquired some further understanding since asking the other question, but still I can't answer a few things.
In said book, we defined the derivative of matrices as $$\frac{dY}{dX} = \frac{d\text{vec}^T(Y)}{d\text{vec}(X)}.$$ We then defined for a structured (toep/symm/etc) matrix $X$, a patterned matrix $X(K)$, where the idea is that the patterned matrix $X(K)$ is a "subset" of $X$. For example, if $X$ is symmetric, then $X(K)$ can be the upper triangular part. After plenty of theory-crafting in chapter 1.3, arises naturally a definition for the differentiation of patterned matrices wrt each other, $$\frac{dY(K_2)}{dX(K_1)} = T(K_1)\frac{dY}{dX}T^T(K_2),$$ where $T(K)$ is such that $T(K)\text{vec}(X) = \text{vec}(X(K))$.
Now here is my issue. At least, as far as I understand, the derivative $\frac{dY}{dX}$ present in the above definition is still 'derivative of structured matrix wrt structured matrix'. For example, if $Y=X \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ symmetric, then $\frac{dY}{dX} \neq I$ but rather $\frac{dY}{dX} = I_{p^2} + K_{p, p} - \text{diag}\left(K_{p, p}\right) $, where $K_{d,d}$ is the commutation matrix and $\text{diag}$ indicates taking the diagonal elements only. I understand that a framework has been presented to take the derivatives of (specific part of a structured matrix) wrt (specific part of a structured matrix), but I still don't know how to take the derivative of (structured matrix) wrt (structured matrix).
For example, given symmetric $\Psi$, what is $\frac{d\Psi^{-1}}{d\Psi}$?

I am not familiar with the notation you are trying to use, but I think I could get the answer your last question even without it. I would simply use row-column indices:
Let $\boldsymbol{\Psi}$ be the matrix and $\Psi_{ij}$ be the i-th row and j-th column of it. Then I can use:
$$
\frac{\partial{\left(\boldsymbol{\Psi\Psi^{-1}}{}\right)}_{ij}}{\partial\left(\boldsymbol{\Psi}\right)_{rt}}=0=\frac{\partial\left(\sum_k\left(\boldsymbol{\Psi}\right)_{ik}\left(\boldsymbol{\Psi}^{-1}\right)_{kj}\right)}{\partial \left(\boldsymbol{\Psi}\right)_{rt}}=\delta_{ir}\left(\boldsymbol{\Psi}^{-1}\right)_{tj}+\sum_k\left(\boldsymbol{\Psi}\right)_{ik}\frac{\partial \left(\boldsymbol{\Psi}^{-1}\right)_{kj}}{\partial \left(\boldsymbol{\Psi}\right)_{rt}}
$$
Where $\delta_{rt}=1$ when $r=t$ and is zero otherwise, basically it is the identity. Then one can re-arrange and multiply by the inverse ($\left(\boldsymbol{\Psi^{-1}}\right)_{si}$):
$$
\frac{\partial \left(\boldsymbol{\Psi}^{-1}\right)_{sj}}{\partial \left(\boldsymbol{\Psi}\right)_{rt}}=-\left(\boldsymbol{\Psi^{-1}}\right)_{sr}\left(\boldsymbol{\Psi^{-1}}\right)_{tj}
$$
Now, this answer does not use any properties of $\Psi$ at all (except using your starting point that assumes that $\Psi$ is invertable). If you are telling me that $\Psi$ is symmetric (and I presume real-valued), then it tells me that $\Psi$ is a normal operator, therefore spectral theorem applies, and there exists basis in which $\Psi$ will be diagonal. Clearly its inverse will have to be diagonal in that basis too.
Lets take the above expression, but in the basis where $\Psi$ is diagonal. Then $\left(\boldsymbol{\Psi}\right)_{ij}=\psi_i \delta_{ij}$ and $\left(\boldsymbol{\Psi}^{-1}\right)_{ij}=\left(1/\psi_i\right) \delta_{ij}$. Then:
$$
\frac{\partial \left(\boldsymbol{\Psi}^{-1}\right)_{ij}}{\partial \left(\boldsymbol{\Psi}\right)_{rt}}=\frac{\partial \psi_i^{-1}}{\partial \psi_r}\delta_{ij}\delta_{rt}=-\frac{1}{\psi_i^2}\,\delta_{ir}\delta_{ij}\delta_{rt}
$$
